# If $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n < \infty$, what can be said about $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$?

Tags: proof-verification

If $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n < \infty$, what can be said about $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$?

My claim is that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = 0$. To see this, first note that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, the series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ converges. Write $L_k = \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have
$$
L_{k+1} = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n \leq a_k + \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = L_k.
$$
So the sequence $\{L_k\}$ is monotone decreasing. Moreover, $0 \leq L_k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. From these two facts, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem for sequences which tells us that

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} L_k \to \inf \{\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n : k \in \mathbb{N}\}.
$$

So it suffices to show that 
$$
\inf \{\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n : k \in \mathbb{N}\} =0.
$$
Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $j > i \geq N$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=i}^j a_n = \left| \sum_{n=i}^j a_n \right| < \epsilon.
$$

Hence, for this $N$ we have

$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n = \lim_{j \to \infty}\sum_{n=N}^j a_n < 0 + \epsilon.
$$
This shows that 
$$
\inf \{\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n : k \in \mathbb{N}\} =0.
$$

Can anyone critique my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is too lengthy.

Note that $$\sum _1^\infty a_n =\sum _1^{k-1} a_n+\sum _{k}^\infty a_n$$
Let $k\to \infty $ and you get $$ \lim _{k\to \infty}\sum _k^\infty a_ n = \sum _1^\infty a_n-\sum _1^\infty a_n=0$$